# How to customize background color of gtable rows in gWidgets (R)

Tags: r, gtk, gwidgets, gtable

Let's say I have a `gtable` in a `gwindow` like this:

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
w <- gwindow()
dat <- data.frame(letter=letters, number=1:length(letters))
tab <- gtable(dat, container=w)
```

I'd like to be able to set the background color of individual rows arbitrarily, such as based on the value of a column of that row (e.g., all rows with vowels turned red).

Is this possible? I don't know a lot about Gtk at all, but I can learn if someone could point me in the right direction, such as, how can I access the row object in order to apply a Gtk function to it to change its color.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: using `gWidgets2` is recommended. There the `$widget` component should be a `gtkTreeView` instance. You would likely need to get the cell renderers and from there modify the `foreground` attribute.

Comment: @jverzani Thanks for the reply. Why is gWidgets2 recommended?

Comment: Because bugs get fixed for that package when they get pointed out. It is also a bit faster in testing.